# What is javascript "global" variable?

Tags: javascript, webpack, breeze, commonjs

I am trying to get my app that uses BreezeJs to work with Webpack/commonjs.

My app is in typescript that compiles down to commonjs javascript.

There is a line in the breeze code that looks like this:

```
function __requireLibCore(libName) {
  var window = global.window;
  if (!window) return; // Must run in a browser. Todo: add commonjs support
```

The problem is that `global` is just an empty object (`{}`).  It does not have window in it.

I can use webpack to make global equal to something, but I don't know what this global object is.  (Try googling for "javascript global")

**Is it a generic typescript construct that somehow is not present in commonjs?**

**Or something specific to breeze?**

Comment: window is already an object made by the browser.  You should have to redefine it?